# How to find photos that do not have any keywords assigned to them in Adobe Bridge?

Tags: file-management, tagging, adobe-bridge

I'm trying to organize my archive using Adobe Bridge. In one step I messed and moved some untagged photos to another folder that all its photos are already tagged. These photos are parts of my everyday street photography photos, so they are taken on different days and can not be distinguished visually.

Is it possible to filter photos that do not have any keywords assigned to them in Adobe Bridge?

I searched the web and couldn't find anything. Perhaps I'm missing the right keywords.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter photos without a keyword in Bidge:

1. Navigate to the folder that has the photos with and without keywords.
2. Go to the Filter panel. If it's not shown, go to **Window** → **Filter panel**.
3. Click on **No Keywords**:

[image]

If your photos without keywords are spread out over multiple folders, you can go to the parent folder, enable **Show Items from Subfolders** and repeat step 2 and 3.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately I can't upvote your post yet due to lack of reputation.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Don't worry about the upvote (I forgot that was a restriction for new users), thanks for marking it as answered.